# A certain relation of a polynomial to its coefficients

Tags: integration, combinatorics, analysis, polynomials

I've got a certain problem:

If $A(t) = a_0+a_1t+ ...+a_Nt^N$, show that:

$a_k = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{-ikx}A(e^{ix})dx$

after some rearrangements I got:

$a_k = \frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{p=0}^{N}a_p(\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{i(k-p)x}dx)$

It is clear that when $p$ is allowed to take only $p=k$ both sides of the equation are equal. This implies that all other summands equate to zero: $\frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{p\neq k}F(p) = 0$

How can I prove that?

Comment: Orthogonality property

Comment: Care to elaborate?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_functions where k does not equal p the integral evaluates to zero from pi to -pi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When $p \neq k$ you have(antiderivative of $\displaystyle e^{i(k-p)x}$ is $\displaystyle \frac{e^{i(p-k)x}}{i(k-p)}$):

$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{i(k-p)x}dx=\frac{e^{i(k-p)\pi}-e^{-i(k-p)\pi}}{i(k-p)}=\frac{2\sin((k-p)\pi)}{k-p}=0$$